# TypeError: jointplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

Where am I going wrong? idk to solve it

`plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))`

`sns.jointplot(data.radius_mean,data.area_mean,kind="reg") plt.show()`

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-3a368da054ef> in <module>
      1 plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
----> 2 sns.jointplot(data.radius_mean,data.area_mean,kind="reg")
      3 plt.show()

TypeError: jointplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

Answer (score 2):

Look the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) for a simple example, for your case this code should work:

```
sns.jointplot(data=data, x='radius_mean', y='area_mean', kind="reg")
```